# Silverlight javascript calling

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, silverlight

I'm calling a javascript funciton from my silverlight with:

HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("small");

however im wanting to wait for this to be completed before i move on.

how do i get my silverlight appliction to wait for this to be completed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call silverlight defined function from javascript when javascript function is done: Here are [tips & tricks](http://michaelsync.net/2008/01/18/silverlight-tipstricks-communicating-between-javascript-and-c) on how to accomplish that.

So.. You can execute javascript function from silverlight, when javascript function is done, you can call silverlight function and notify your application that javascript is done with interpreting.